# Using Planet MBTiles instead of Country level MBtiles

Tags: openmaptiles

We are using the TileServer-GL from OpenMapTiles to render our own maps.

I was wondering if there is any performance loss in using a Planet MBTiles file instead of doing it for every single country. The TileServer seems to be using one source mbtiles file (and since we have styled it). If we have to add other sources, we will have to duplicate the styles and the identifiers in the style.json to match that.

Is there any disadvantage in using a massive 50GB Planet MBTiles instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is no disadvantage in using the planet MBTiles.